# Simple local planner in Python?

Tags: ros, rospy, teb-local-planner, dwa-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I would like to implement my own local planner using Python for exercise purposes. Therefore, I make no use of move_base and the ROS navigation stack at all and try to implement those parts (localization, global planner, local planner) in Python. Since algorithms like dwa or teb seem pretty advance to me and I am not too experienced in robotics and Python my question is the following: Is there any local planning algorithm in existence that is feasible to implement for beginners? Any 'light weight' versions of the local planners implemented in the ROS navigation stack?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368839/simple-local-planner-in-python?/) by [ba_tma](https://answers.ros.org/users/66692/ba_tma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2021-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

An excellent resource to consider is Python Robotics: https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/PythonRobotics/tree/master/PathPlanning

Under Path Planning there are many examples. The examples are as simple as possible primarily in 2D but you can use them as a foundation.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3